# How to redirect calls from one hard drive to another in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, dropbox

I'm sharing a database that an app runs on in my dropbox and have symlinked the database from the roaming folder location to the dropbox location.

Everything is working great but one thing. The database has location paths that point to a computer's F: drive directory and the computer I am trying to sync does not have it's mirrored files in the F: directory, it has them in the C: directory.

Can I tell Windows to map all F: drive calls to C: drive calls?

### Update

I've found that I can user Window's environmental variables to act as a dynamic link that can befined on each different computer uniquely... but it still did not solve my problem as my application is a FireFox app and written in JS and the JS does not import my environmental library as far as I can tell.

Comment: Running this command as administrator should do the trick: `reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices" /v "F:" /t REG_SZ /d "\DosDevices\C:" /f` Let me know whether this solution works for your use case so I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Disk Management to add F: as another drive letter pointing to the same volume as C:? You can have more than one drive letter referencing the same volume.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-add-remove-drive-letter

Comment: I was able to do this using command line tool subst f: c:\ but I had to add a task manager task to run it at start up every PC boot.